# How can one set a sequential delay on adding a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, coffeescript, underscore.js

I'm using jQuery UI plugin and the latest jQuery.

I would like to sequentially add on the class, one by one down my array of elements. Right now I have this :

```
$(@el).addClass("gridBoxComplete", 400, "easeOutBounce").delay(800)
```

Where `@el` is the current element in the array. This, however, does not delay this object before the next item in the iteration is run. I based this animation roughly off of this idea..

```
$(@).hide().each (index) ->
  $(@)
    .delay(index * 100)
    .fadeIn 500
```

Comment: I have no idea what that cofeecrap does, but `delay()` is for animations, and not for adding classes, use a timeout.

Comment: Do either of you know a good source of criticism against coffeescript I could read? I've had nothing but a good time so far..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`delay()` delays animations, not classname changes or other code executions. If you want generic execution delay, use `setTimeout` or something like:

```
$.fn.wait = function(ms, callback) {
  return this.each(function() {
    setTimeout(callback.bind(this), ms)
  })
}

$(@el).addClass("gridBoxComplete", 400, "easeOutBounce").wait(800, function() {
    $(this).addClass("something");
});
```

Comment: Hmmm.. this custom function is returning `unexpected identifier`