# Sequential addClass loop (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, addclass

So I've got 5 divs in a row on my page. I'm using [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) to add a class, `is-active` to the first one, which changes the appearance of it. I then want there to be a delay, say 1 second, when it adds to the next one, and then 1 second after that, the next, and so on. Here is my code:

```
<div class="five-step-waypoint"></div>
<div class="steps">
    <div class="step">Step 1</div>
    <div class="step">Step 2</div>
    <div class="step">Step 3</div>
    <div class="step">Step 4</div>
    <div class="step">Step 5</div>
</div>
```

and my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.wait = function( ms, callback ) {
        return this.each(function() {
            window.setTimeout((function( self ) {
                return function() {
                    callback.call( self );
                }
            }( this )), ms );
        });
    };

    $('.five-step-waypoint').waypoint(function() {
        $(".step:first-child").addClass("is-active");
         $.each($(".step").wait(1000, function() {
             $(this).addClass("is-active");
         }));
    }, {
        triggerOnce: true
    });
});
```

Note: I got the 'wait' function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213214/how-can-one-set-a-sequential-delay-on-adding-a-class). Feel free to modify it or remove it altogether if you can do something better.

The problem I have is that the first `.step` has `.is-active` added to it, the 1 second delay is observed, but then `.is-active` is added to the other 4 `.step`s all at once. I need it to add `.is-active` one-by-one. Also if it could loop round (so that when each `.step` has `.is-active`, it clears all the `.is-active`s and returns to the beginning again) that would be great!

Thanks for any help anyone gives me! I have also written a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bXQAc/) for you to test stuff in. I have omitted the Waypoints stuff though to make it easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the wait is applied to all step elements at once. To get a staggered wait a common technique is to have a function that performs one step of the work and uses `setTimeout` to schedule another call to itself in the future:

```
$('.five-step-waypoint').waypoint(function() {
    var children = $(".step");
    var index = 0;

    function addClassToNextChild() {
        if (index == children.length) return;
        children.eq(index++).addClass("is-active");
        window.setTimeout(addClassToNextChild, 1000);
    }

    addClassToNextChild();
}, {
    triggerOnce: true
});
```

**[See updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bXQAc/1/)**.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. I knew that something was wrong with the delay but I didn't know how to change it to add it to each one individually. Thanks!